# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException after trying to import preferences in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, exception

I was trying to import a preference in eclipse.
When I clicked on File> Import > General > Preferences, I got a

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

[image]

**Error Log:**

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
          at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:639)
          at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.convertFromProperties(PreferencesService.java:266)
          at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.readPreferences(PreferencesService.java:898)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesImportPage1.getTransfers(WizardPreferencesImportPage1.java:79)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesPage.setPreferenceTransfers(WizardPreferencesPage.java:237)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesImportPage1.setPreferenceTransfers(WizardPreferencesImportPage1.java:129)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesImportPage1.handleEvent(WizardPreferencesImportPage1.java:213)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1084)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.setText(Combo.java:2335)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesPage.setDestinationValue(WizardPreferencesPage.java:940)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesPage.restoreWidgetValues(WizardPreferencesPage.java:904)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.wizards.preferences.WizardPreferencesPage.createControl(WizardPreferencesPage.java:187)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:175)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:696)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1144)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1197)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$2(WizardDialog.java:1185)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$$Lambda$77.0000000020DF20A0.run(Unknown Source)
          at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
          at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1185)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ImportExportPage.treeDoubleClicked(ImportExportPage.java:232)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ImportPage$2.doubleClick(ImportPage.java:77)
          at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:833)
          at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
          at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
          at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:830)
          at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1470)
          at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1264)
          at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
          at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
          at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
          at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
          at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Import.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:158)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
          at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
          at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
          at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
          at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
          at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
          at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
          at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
          at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:353)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:155)
          at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
          at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
          at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$$Lambda$36.000000000394CC20.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
          at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
          at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
          at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
          at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
          at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
          at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
          at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
          at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
          at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
          at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
          at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
          at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
          at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
          at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
          at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
          at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
          at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.m
```

I did google but didn't come across this bug.
Any way to fix this other than a fresh re-installation?

*NOTE: This doesn't happen when I try to **export** a preference.*

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? What version did you export the settings from?

Comment: Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500 

The thing is, the window for importing is not popping up. It just pops this exception as soon as I click on the preferences icon in the import wizard.

Comment: Anything in the error log? <Workspacefolder>/.metadata/.log

Comment: @fredrik i have updated the question with the error log..

Comment: The code in PreferenceServices is:
    String path = (String) entry.getKey();
   String value = (String) entry.getValue();
   if (path.charAt(0) == EXPORT_ROOT_PREFIX) {
so it seems like your preference file is for some reason broken. Maybe, carefully editing it could help or give some insight,